# el-radio-group doesn't work after navigating back to page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, radio-button, vue-component

I've a el-radio-group in Vuejs with 2 values 'Yes' and 'No'. A default value is selected 'Yes' for first time. Suppose I select 'No' and then if I click on a link which takes me to another page, and then I click back button in browser, the default value doesn't sets again. It remains 'No' selected. And my el-radio-group stops working i.e., I'm unable to switch between values.
What I want is when I come back, again 'Yes' is selected.
Here's my code:

```
<el-radio-group v-model="choice">
     <el-radio-button
          label="yes"
     >
     </el-radio-button>
     <el-radio-button
           label="no"
     >
     </el-radio-button>
</el-radio-group>

<div @click="clickHere"> Click Here </div>
........

data () {
    return {
       choice: 'yes',
       .....
    }
},
methods: {
    clickHere() {
        window.location.href('/register/')
    }
 ........
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported bug in Chrome. Issue raised over [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/11165). The bug is still Open but there's a workaround for this.
To change `pageshow` event for Chrome only.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome/') > 0) {
  window.addEventListener('pageshow', () => {
    new Vue({
      render: (h) => h(App),
    }).$mount('#app');
  });
} else {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    new Vue({
      render: (h) => h(App),
    }).$mount('#app');
  });
}
```

Solution provided [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/11165#issuecomment-637633436).